# Im not expert in css i need a help to change a button colorea

Tags: html, css, popup

I have a css with css I call to `<a></a>` tag and that css converts that tag to button

I want a orange color button not in green I don't know what was the changes to do in css please help me in this.

Here is a css below:

```
    .button {
        width:138px;
        height:33px;

        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:33px;

        color:#fff;
        text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

        -webkit-border-radius:3px;
        -moz-border-radius:3px;
        border-radius:3px;

        -webkit-box-shadow:
            inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5),
            0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        -moz-box-shadow:
            inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5),
            0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        box-shadow:
            inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5),
            0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

        float:left;
    }
    .button img { 
        float:left;
        width:33px;
        height:33px;
    }
    .button.green {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(170,212,79,1) 0%,rgba(116,185,49,1) 90%,rgba(106,173,45,1) 95%,rgba(96,157,41,1) 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(170,212,79,1) 0%,rgba(116,185,49,1) 90%,rgba(106,173,45,1) 95%,rgba(96,157,41,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(170,212,79,1) 0%,rgba(116,185,49,1) 90%,rgba(106,173,45,1) 95%,rgba(96,157,41,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(170,212,79,1) 0%,rgba(116,185,49,1) 90%,rgba(106,173,45,1) 95%,rgba(96,157,41,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(170,212,79,1) 0%,rgba(116,185,49,1) 90%,rgba(106,173,45,1) 95%,rgba(96,157,41,1) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aad44f', endColorstr='#609d29',GradientType=0 );

        border:1px solid #5b8821;

        margin:0 5px 0 35px;
    }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    #modal {
        width:284px;
        height:156px;
        padding:8px;

        margin-left:-150px !important;
        margin-top:-78px;
    }
    #heading {
        width:284px;
        height:28px;

        line-height:28px;
        font-size:0.688em;
    }
    #content {
        width:284px;
        height:128px;
    }
    #content p {
        width:284px;
        font-size:0.688em;
    }
    .button img { 
        width:23px;
        height:23px;
    }
    .button {
        width:108px;
        height:23px;

        line-height:23px;
        font-size:0.688em;
    }
    .button.green {
        margin:0 4px 0 28px !important;
    }
    .button.red {
        margin:0 28px 0 4px !important;
    }
}
```

I want to change a green button to orange color please help me out where I need to do this in css for change color green to orange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style for .button_green

```
.button.green
    {
    /* Note: This gradient may render differently in browsers that don't support the unprefixed gradient syntax */

    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FF9854 0%, #EFB55D 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FF9854 0%, #EFB55D 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FF9854 0%, #EFB55D 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FF9854), color-stop(1, #EFB55D));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FF9854 0%, #EFB55D 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FF9854 0%, #EFB55D 100%);

    border:1px solid #5b8821;

    margin:0 5px 0 35px;

    }
```